# TestNG test passes on Linux, fails on windows

Tags: java, testng

For some reason the test below fails on Windows, but passes on Linux. The test is designed to generate an exception in the code being tested. The exception is basically a file exception. The approach is to make the file unreadable in order to generate the exception. It        looks like the setReadable(false) has no affect on Windows.

```
 @Test(dependsOnGroups = "expectedFlow",expectedExceptions = ParserException.class)
 @Parameters("unreadableFile")
 public void mineDataParserExceptionTest(String unreadableFile) throws ParserException{
  AbstractParser parser;
  File f = new File(unreadableFile);
  f.setReadable(false);
  parser = ParserFactory.getParser(ParserFactory.TYPES.SAR);
  parser.mine(fileHelper, xml);
}
```

Comment: What is result of **f.setReadable(false);**? What exception does it throw?

Comment: What is the value of unreadableFile? (path format are different on linux and windows)

Comment: f.setReadable(false) doesn't throw an exception. It either returns a boolean true/false. It does however,  affect the operation of the parser.mine(fileHelper,xml) which happens two lines later. The parser will try to open the file which has been set to unreadable and it should then generate an exception.

Comment: The path to unreadableFile is a unix path: src/test/resources/file... other tests in the same suite are using the unix path without complaining though.

Comment: As you said, setReadable() returns a boolean. So, what's the returned value. The javadoc says: *return true if and only if the operation succeeded. The operation will fail if the user does not have permission to change the access permissions of this abstract pathname. If readable is false and the underlying file system does not implement a read permission, then the operation will fail.*

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return value to see if it succeeded; however, it seems likely that `f.setReadable(false, false);` might be a better idea, since otherwise it is only supposed to alter the read permission for the *owner* of the file.